# EditorJS does not want to insert formatted text with block elements into a component with <div contenteditable="true">

Tags: javascript, editorjs

EditorJS does not want to insert formatted text with block elements into a component with `<div contenteditable="true">`. When you insert text with paragraphs, EditorJS inserts the text as separate components at the bottom, not in the `<div>`.

When I insert text with paragraphs into a `<div contenteditable="true">`, I get components with text at the bottom as a result.

Comment: Hi! Looking at [editorjs] I'm not sure if EditorJS has a large community of support here on SO, in this case I actually I think you might be able to get better support in their Telegram group and GitHub issues